# default value is getting submitted in database

Tags: php, html

I am using this text-area so that user can write some text here ,I am using `onblur` and `onfocus`  so that when user click on default text it is not shown,I am providing some message as default value ,problem is that when user write something in this text-area than default value is also getting stored in db with other text typed  ,where is the mistake ?
 I am taking value in this variable `$nature_speci`

```
 $nature_speci = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['other_naturespeci']));
```

and this is text-area html code

```
<textarea id="other_naturespeci" name="other_naturespeci" size="30" maxlength="100"  onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Assignment Specification in Few Words.<?php if (isset($errors)) { echo $_POST['other_naturespeci'];}elseif(isset($_GET['other_naturespeci'])){ echo $_GET['other_naturespeci'];} ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use the  placeholder instead of onblur & onfocus

```
<textarea id="other_naturespeci" name="other_naturespeci" size="30" maxlength="100"  placeholder="defaulttext">Assignment Specification in Few Words.<?php if (isset($errors)) { echo $_POST['other_naturespeci'];}elseif(isset($_GET['other_naturespeci'])){ echo $_GET['other_naturespeci'];} ?>
</textarea>
```

This is the html5 advantage. see the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onblur` and `onfocus` why dont you use the new HTML5 attribute `placeholder`. It currently is supported by all the browsers except IE.

If you want to show it in IE aswell, you could then use a javascript shim to show it. For instance, if you're using jQuery, you could use https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim